# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'guid' on string 'option:selected'

Tags: jquery, ajax

Doing cascading Drop down when I call it with Ajax receiving this error. Can anyone help me out?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#os").change(function () {
        debugger

        var osid = $(this).select("option:selected").val();
        alert("heloo");

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Products/OsVersions/" + osid,
            type: "Get",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#osvdiv").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

@Html.DropDownList("os", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.OSList, "- 
Operating System -", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: You have a bug in your program. Since you haven't posted the code, we can't possibly guess where it is.

Comment: barmar please check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `.select()` method incorrectly, you should be using `.find()`.

```
var osid = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
```

Or you can simply write:

```
var osid = $(this).val();
```

since the value of a dropdown is the same as the value of the selected option.